# white screen between splash screen and startup screen index.html sencha touch after app build package

Tags: android, ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I build my app package,everything seems to be working fine but it is showing white screen for 2 secs on the device after splash screen. I saw lot of questions on this issue but didnt find apt solution where my app is going wrong. I am using phone gap.Please help me

Here is my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html manifest="" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta
    charset="UTF-8">
        <meta
        name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

        <title>Test  APP </title>
         <link  href="touch/resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script src="touch/sencha-touch-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="js-cordova/ios/cordova-2.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="js-cordova/ios/barcodescanner.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script  type="text/javascript">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady,true);
                             document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown,false);
               function onDeviceReady()
                  {
                      setTimeout(function()
                      {
                         navigator.splashscreen.hide();

                       },50000);
                            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown,false);
                            }

                            </script>
     <style type="text/css">  
        html, body {
                  height: 100%;
                  background-color: #7f1a1a;
                  background : url('uploads/Samsung.png') center no-repeat;
              }
       #appLoadingIndicator {       
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -15px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

            }
       #appLoadingIndicator > * {
                 display: inline-block;
                height: 30px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                margin: 0 5px;
                width: 30px;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

      @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
        0% {
             opacity: 0.8
           }
       50% {
             opacity: 0
           }
       100% {
             opacity: 0.8
           }
         }
  </style>
 <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appLoadingIndicator">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added cordova splashscreen plugin to avoid the white between corodova screen and sencha load  and now I am using sencha touch2.3 which comes along with cordova so I dont see any white screens now.